# How do I capture the last two characters in this regex?

Tags: regex

So far I have this

```
lastUpdatedTimestamp":.+?:..
```

Sample Test String

```
{"availableSpots":3,"trend":"STATIC","lastUpdatedTimestamp":"2018-12-21T14:50:03Z"},"probability":[{}]},
```

I want the `50`

Comment: What's the tool/language?

Comment: It looks like you're parsing JSON.  I would strongly suggest you use a tool that will parse the JSON for you and access your datapoint that way.

Comment: And then I'd suggest using a too designed to parse timestamps in this format instead of using a regex yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for the part you want to extract:

```
lastUpdatedTimestamp":.+?:(..)
```

Then use your tool's mechanism to get the value of the first capturing group.

You can use [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if your tool supports it. Since most lookbehind implementations require fixed lookbehind-size, you'd need to remove the quantifier `+?` and — for example — use the exact number of symbols, i.e.:

```
(?<=lastUpdatedTimestamp":.{14}:)..
```

Comment: this is for a script, and i can't do any processing after extracting regex.  is there anyway to do this right in the regex?

Comment: which tool/regex engine are you using?

Comment: I tried this also, but if you put this in regex101.com, you get Full match, Group 1, Group 2...  if i use that in my script it won't work because i'll just get the Full match.  (lastUpdatedTimestamp\":\")(.*?)\"

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample, you can use:

```
\d:(\d+):\d
```

or:

```
:(\d+):
```

---

You didn't specify the programming language you are using, but generically, the result is in capturing group 1

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WCsv3l/1)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

[image]